# Search through a BST in Standard ML

Tags: types, binary-search-tree, sml

The requirement is simple - given a root node and an *integer* to find, return whether or not the value is in the tree.

Here is the data structure:

```
 datatype either = ImAString of string | ImAnInt of int;
```

Here is the tree structure:

```
 datatype eitherTree =
          Internal of {data: either, left: eitherTree, right: eitherTree}
        | Leaf of either
```

The function I have so far is:

```
 fun eitherSearch (Leaf (ImAnInt i)) find = 
         if i = find then true else false
   | eitherSearch (Internal {left, right, (ImAnInt i)}) find = 
         ....
```

I have tested the first clause by itself, and the type extraction seems to work
just fine there, but when I try to extract the **(ImAnInt i)** from the second clause I get an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like your pattern matching on records syntax is slightly off. `| eitherSearch (Internal {data = x, left = left, right = right}) find`